# checking day difference with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to use moment.js to check if a date is today. Does anyone know how to do that?

I tried `moment(yesterday_date).diff(moment(), 'days')`. This outputs a 1 only if there is a 24 hour difference.

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startOf('day')` and `isSame()` to do this...

```
var someDate = moment("2014-07-17 05:00:00");
var isToday = someDate.startOf('day').isSame(moment().startOf('day'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHXWR/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
moment().unix() - moment(yesterday_date).unix();
```

That should give you the difference in milliseconds. Then you just need to convert to whichever time unit you need.

**Edit:**
Just realised you want to check whether it's today. Then something like this should work:

```
function isToday(dateString) {
    var today = moment();
    var prevDate = moment(dateString);
    return today.date() == prevDate.date() && today.month() == prevDate.month() && today.year() == prevDate.year();
}
```